# Is there a way to enable users to create their own project on TFS-Azure DevOps without being a collection admin?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm a TFS admin and I'd like to make few users autonomous in order to create their projects on in and manage them.

But at the same time I don't want them to be able to modify and access previous projects that are not related to their job.

Is it possible to make this kind of segregation happen?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 8):

To create a new project the user need "Create new projects" permissions, by default these permissions exist only to "Projects Collections Administrators" that give full access toe everything.

What you can do is to create a new group and in the collection level permissions give to these group the "Create new projects" permissions and deny other permissions that you don't want they will do.

After they create the project they can put themselves as a "Project Admin" and manage their projects.

In this way you give to the users the ability to create and manage new projects but they can't touch in another projects.